# Payara Server seems started, but not running

Tags: glassfish, payara, connection-refused

Payara Server seems started, but not running. I don't know why.

Command start-domain executed succesfuly.

Then, I try to stop server, it prompts the message "No domains are currently running."

Screenshot is added below.

Anyone has idea?

```
PS C:\payara-5.2022.3\glassfish\bin> .\asadmin start-domain domain1
Waiting for domain1 to start
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: C:\payara-5.2022.3\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log File: C:\payara-5.2022.3\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.

PS C:\payara-5.2022.3\glassfish\bin> .\asadmin stop-domain domain1
CLI306: Warning - The server located at C:\payara-5.2022.3\glassfish\domains\domain1 is not running.
No domains are currently running.
Command stop-domain failed.
PS C:\payara-5.2022.3\glassfish\bin>
```

[image]

Comment: Any clue? Any idea?

Comment: Did you solve this? Does the domain actually start up successfully, what does the server log say after finishing the start-domain command?

Comment: Yes, I solved. I am starting server via powershell. The problem is solved when I started powershell as admin. so silly. 